i have this error on my django app i tried every solution possible but it remains the same
so im trying to build a realtime chat application for my college project and i used django because i heard that its preety flexible to use as webframewoke app but since i started i kept facing errors, i had a solution for most of them but i got stuck in this error so i need help
#forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class SignupForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']

#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('members/', views.members, name='members'),
    path('', views.frontpage, name='frontpage'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='members\login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]

#views.py
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


from .forms import SignUpForm

def frontpage(request):
    return render(request, 'members\frontpage.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request)
            return redirect('frontpage')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'members/signup.html', {'form': form})

#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank= True, editable=True) 
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, editable= True)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, editable= True)

#the error message
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 519, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chat\chat\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('members.urls')),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chat\members\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chat\members\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import SignUpForm
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chat\members\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class SignupForm(UserChangeForm):
  File "C:\Users\bdjam\OneDrive\Bureau\project\chatapp\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 332, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for User

gJHVJ

You're not defining the User model correctly. It should sub-class AbstractBaseUser not models.Model, then you need to import and use the User model you created in the UserCreationForm.

in your forms.py you are importing django's inbuilt User model that's why its giving error: Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for User
Solution:
Import User model from the models.py in forms.py:
from .models import User

# then class definition:
class SignupForm(UserChangeForm):

